# CGAL mesh voxelization

Tags: mesh, cgal

Does CGAL provide a method of surface mesh voxelization, like iso2mesh for
matlab?
Also does CGAL provides image processing methods - imerode, imdilate,
imclose - like matlabs image processing toolbox?

Answer (score 0):

CGAL does not provide what you want. We only offer functions to extract iso-surfaces from voxel data, or to tetrahedrize the volumes between such surfaces.